# Bash String Comparison sha256sum

Tags: linux, bash, cryptography, sha256

I am trying to compare the hash of a copied file with bash but the condition is not working.

```
└──╼ $bash check-256.sh cal.sh 2cal.sh 

ea8f4b5acdeb26015661ee27c9000af97691a0fd715be94b2b3eda6a3d02c789  cal.sh
ea8f4b5acdeb26015661ee27c9000af97691a0fd715be94b2b3eda6a3d02c789  2cal.sh
```

```
#!/bin/bash
First_file=$(sha256sum $1)
Second_file=$(sha256sum $2)
echo "$First_file"
echo "$Second_file"
[ "$First_file" == "$Second_file" ] &&  echo "Pass" || echo "Fail"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition fails, because the resulting strings are actually not the same. You need to cut out the hash by using the cut command.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
First_file=$(sha256sum $1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
Second_file=$(sha256sum $2 | cut -d' ' -f1)
echo "$First_file"
echo "$Second_file"
[ "$First_file" == "$Second_file" ] &&  echo "Pass" || echo "Fail"
```

```
cut -d' ' -f1
```

- -d specifies the delimiter. In this case we use a single space
- -f1 selects the field of the output. Here we want to only have the first field, which is the hash

Comment: Or use redirection so the filename isn't there to start with: `first=$(sha256sum <$1)` etc.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 didn't think of that. In this example this would be the cleaner way

Comment: You could also strip the filename as part of the variable substitutions: `[ "${First_file%% *}" = "${Second_file%% *}" ]` (the `%% *` part basically means "remove the longest suffix that starts with a space").