# How to check SHA-256 checksum on files?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh, sha

I know that you can use `shasum -a 256 filename` to create a SHA-256 checksum for a file, but how can one automate the check if known SHA-256 matches a file on a mac?

Since the Mac shell is zsh by default, but our CI runner uses bash, I want to know both versions (for local testing and for the ci).

Comment: You can compare two files for equality using `cmp`. BTW, why is this tagged _bash_  and _zsh_? Please make up your mind in which language you are going to write your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Using the `awk '{ print $1 }'`, you can omit the filename printed by `shasum`. This way you can write an easy if statement to check if the SHA checksums match.

zsh version

```
sha=$( shasum -a 256 filename | awk '{ print $1 }')
if [[ $sha == "known checksum" ]] {
  echo "sha matches"
} else {
  echo $sha "does not match the required: known checksum"
}
```

bash version

```
sha=$( shasum -a 256 filename | awk '{ print $1 }')
if [[ $sha == "known checksum" ]]
then
  echo "sha matches"
else
  echo $sha "does not match the required: known checksum"
fi
```

Comment: You don't need a pipe to awk, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72642521/bash-string-comparison-sha256sum#comment128318698_72642618. Also, don't use all upper case for non-exported variables, see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).